# How to get a token in postman, which we will then use on the front

Tags: javascript, json

I'm new to this field, I'm doing a task, I need to get a token in postman
When trying to get a token, I get a refusal in postman

```
{
    "errors": [{
        "msg": "Пользователь уже существует"
    }]
}
```

at the same time, the script stops working[error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXbum.png)

```
    const express = require('express');
    const router = express.Router();
    const config = require('config');

    const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
    const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
    const {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator');

    const User = require('../models/User');

    router.post('/', [
        check('name', 'Укажите имя пользователя').not().isEmpty(),
        check('email', 'Укажите корректный email адрес').isEmail(),
        check('password', 'Укажите пароль длинной не менее 6 символов').isLength({ min:6 })
    ], async(req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({errors: errors.array() });
        }
        const { name, email, password } = req.body;
        try {
            let user = await User.findOne({ email })
            if (user) {
                res.status(400).json({ errors: [{msg: 'Пользователь уже существует'}]});
        }
        user = new User({name, email, password});
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);
        await user.save();
        const payload = {
            user : {id: user.id}
        };
        jwt.sign(payload, config.get('jwtSecret'), {expiresIn: 36000},
        (err, token) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.json({ token })
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I haven't tried anything, because I don't know what the error is

Answer (score 0):

here you are signing to get a token and sending it as a response

```js
const payload = {
    user : {id: user.id}
};
jwt.sign(payload, config.get('jwtSecret'), {expiresIn: 36000},
(err, token) => {
    if (err) throw err;
        res.json({ token })
});
```

If you have not integrated a frontend then log the token before sending the response

```js
jwt.sign(payload, config.get('jwtSecret'), {expiresIn: 36000},
    (err, token) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('token')
        res.json({ token })
    });
```

You can get this log in your terminal.

Copy that log and go to postman

1. make a new request for POST method
2. By default you will be at params option ,then go to Authorization
3. Select the type Bearer Token
4. a box will appear, paste the token there

Comment: I don't quite understand you
at my request in postman:
{
"name": "New Name of User",
"email": "newName@gmail.com",
"password": "somepass"
}
postman should give me a token

Comment: There are two options: either he writes the error that I indicated at the very beginning: "the user already exists." Either "Server Error" and the script throws the following error: "Configuration property "jwtSecret" is not defined"